# Tkinter get width of button made with `create_window()`

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter combined with Python Turtle Graphics and I want to be able to get the width of a button made using `create_window()`.

I am able to set the value using the code below, but I want to get the value rather than set it. How do I do this please?

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

screen = turtle.Screen()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()

button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Press me")
w1 = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=button)

canvas.itemconfig(w1, width=100)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

screen = turtle.Screen()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()

button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Press me")
w1 = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=button)

canvas.itemconfig(w1, width=100)

button.update()
print(button.winfo_width())
print(button.winfo_height())

turtle.done()
```

Make sure to update before calling .winfo_width(). :-)